# i implement it xsockect.net webrtc sample

Tags: asp.net, webrtc, xsockets.net

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Exceptions.ExportException: Tipo de excepção 'XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Exceptions.ExportException' accionado.

Source Error:

```
Line 11:         public static void Start()
Line 12:         {
Line 13:             wss = XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Composable.GetExport<IXSocketServerContainer>();
Line 14:             wss.StartServers();
Line 15:         }
```

Comment: Posting the English translation of the error would be helpful.

Comment: You have to post something more than these lines.
Where are you running the code? What kind of project?